# How to display a custom post as a page (but unedited)?

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, page-template

In my plugin (my first one), I inserted 2 posts with a custom post_type ('foo' for this example). This kind of post is exactly like a page but which is unedited (so hidden in the admin. interface).
I would like to display this post on the front-end as a page (so with the template: page.php) when the user click on the button with the url :
- mysiteurl.com?post_type=foo&p=140 where 140 is the post ID.

I get this error

> Trying to get property of non-object in ...\wordpress\wp-includes\canonical.php on line 120

```
<?php

namespace MyNameSpace\FrontEnd;

class FrontEnd {

    public function __construct(){

        // Include dependencies
        $this->include_dependencies();

        // Initialize the components
        $this->init();

    }

    private function include_dependencies(){
         ...
    }

    private function init(){


        add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'foo_subs_form_page_template'), 99 );
        ...


    }

    public function foo_subs_form_page_template( $template ) {

        if ( is_page( 'foo' )  ) {
            $new_template = locate_template( array( 'page.php' ) );
            if ( '' != $new_template ) {
                return $new_template;
            }
        }

        return $template;
    }
}
```

What do I need for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !
To display the post as a page, I needed to do these steps :

1) Register the post type

```
private function init(){
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_post_type') );
}

public function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'foo',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Foos' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Foo' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => false,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => false,
            'rewrite' => true //<-- Important !
        )
    );
}
```

2) Choose the template

```
 private function init(){
    add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_post_type') );
    add_filter( 'template_include', array( $this, 'foo_page_template'), 99 );
}

public function foo_page_template( $template ) {
    if ( get_post_type() === 'foo' ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'page.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

3) (Optional) Add body classes

```
add_action( 'body_class', array($this , 'add_body_classes' ));

public function add_body_classes( $classes ) {

    // Add custom class
    $classes[] = 'page';
    $classes[] = 'page-two-column';

    return $classes;
}
```

The href was changed by **mysiteurl.com/foo/my-post-name** and that works if you do not forget **'rewrite' => true** when you use **register_post_type()** !

Answer (score 0):

To use `page.php` specifically, you can use the [`template_include` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include).

You could also copy `page.php` in your theme, saving it as `single-foo.php`, and it would then be used for your "foo" CPT's individual posts. You would want to do this in a custom or child theme rather than editing a parent theme directly, so that whenever your theme is updated, you don't lose this edit.

Comment: It's a plugin development, it's completely separate of the theme. This post is exactly a page so I would like to avoid to make a template (which will be the copy of page.php)

Comment: So, using the `template_include` filter will serve your purposes.

Comment: Sorry but maybe is a part of the solution but that does not work.

Comment: To check something in template_include, I already need to get post information... I do not magae to get it :/

Comment: Here are a couple of other options specifically for plugins: http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/  --  http://jeroensormani.com/how-to-add-template-files-in-your-plugin/